# Yii Configuration with Cloud Control Error cctrluser key.add

Tags: yii, cloudcontrol

I am configuring YII framework using Cloud Control, I am trying to generate SSH Key using Command Prompt in Windows PC. I installed cctrl 1.8.5 in my PC. After installing application I typed cctrluser key.add at Command Prompt, I received below mentioned error. Could someone please help?

```
C:\Users\sumit>cctrluser key.add
Key 'C:\Users\sumit/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' seems to be invalid or not found!
Type "Yes" to generate a new default SSH-key pair: yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cctrluser", line 150, in <module>
  File "cctrluser", line 34, in main
  File "cctrluser", line 144, in parse_cmdline
  File "cctrl\common.pyo", line 99, in run
  File "cctrl\user.pyo", line 124, in addKey
  File "cctrl\keyhelpers.pyo", line 149, in create_new_default_ssh_keys
  File "cctrl\keyhelpers.pyo", line 57, in generate_rsa_keys
  File "cctrl\keyhelpers.pyo", line 85, in generate_rsa_key_manually
  File "cctrl\keyhelpers.pyo", line 101, in generate_private_rsa_key_file
  File "paramiko\__init__.pyo", line 65, in <module>
  File "paramiko\transport.pyo", line 45, in <module>
  File "paramiko\ecdsakey.pyo", line 24, in <module>
ImportError: No module named ecdsa
```

Comment: I have the same problem with cloudcontrol under windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution .

Get Git Bash.

Then use the following command :

```
$ ssh-keygen -C youremail@provider.com
```

Save the ssh created into id_rsa ( default, suggested place )

youremail@provider.com is the email you used to create the cloudcontrol account .

Then go into your cloudcontrol account and add the content of the ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub in the SSH keys input .

Answer (score 0):

New [cctrl](https://www.cloudcontrol.com/download/win) version has been released today with fixed ecdsa dependency, so automatic ssh key generation is supported again.